# ion-radio with ngmodel doesn't work after upgrade from v3 to v4

Tags: forms, ionic4

I'm trying to upgrade a project I have from ionic v3 to ionic v4. However, I have a problem with template driven forms. I have the following:

```html
<ion-list [class]="myradio.isValidClass" radio-group [(ngModel)]="myradio.value" ngDefaultControl>
<ion-radio-group>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Option1</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="option1" [disabled]="myradio.disable"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Option2</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="option2" [disabled]="myradio.disable"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

and in the corresponding ts file:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent  {

  private myradio = {
    value: '',
    disable: false,
    isValidClass: 'ng-valid'
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  submit() {
    console.log(this.myradio);
  }
}
```

What I was expecting after I have chosen a radio and submit, is to give me `console.log(this.myradio)` a value, e.g. this.myradio.value=option1 or option2. However, it gives the initial value, i.e. an empty string.

In ionic v3 it was working as expected...what am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. In v3 I didn't have ngDefaultControl. In v4 without it, it was giving me an error which was saying " Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute" in form.js. After little research the solution was to add ngDefaultControl.

Comment: try putting the ngmodel in ion-radio-group and check you are getting the selected value

Comment: You're joking...yeap...this was it! I didn't think of it!

Comment: we have to try for alternate solution that's why I asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `ngModel` in the `ion-radio-group` tag. `ion-list` tag does not support `ngModel` that's the reason the selected value not bound to the model

```html
<ion-list [class]="myradio.isValidClass" radio-group>
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="myradio.value">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Option1</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="option1" [disabled]="myradio.disable"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Option2</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="option2" [disabled]="myradio.disable"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
```